# Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.artifact.Operations' com.android.build.api.artifact.Operations

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, build.gradle

i want to code a long with this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTGNaFwCuxg&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCT-lTlkOmE-PpRkuyNXq6sW&index=2&ab_channel=PhilippLackner

Im using this inital project repo
https://github.com/philipplackner/SpotifyCloneYT

After adding the dependencies for firestore i get this error:

> Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.artifact.Operations'
> com.android.build.api.artifact.Operations
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

**my build.gradle(app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plcoding.spotifycloneyt"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'

    // Architectural Components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // Activity KTX for viewModels()
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02"

    // Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    // Firebase Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.1'
    // Firebase Storage KTX
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:24.10.1'

    // Firebase Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'

    // ExoPlayer
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.8"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.8"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.11.8"
}
```

And build.gradle(project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28.3-alpha"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Other possible solutions found here, but none worked

Comment: Have you tried to follow this instruction, "Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)"?

Comment: Yes, it just appears again everytime